# Electron application is missing some files only when installing the ".exe" file

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, vite, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron application with these versions:
`electron` - 22.0.0
`electron-builder` - 23.6.0
`async` npm package - 3.2.4

This is my electron-builder configuration file:

```js
module.exports = {
    appId: 'com.electron.balbdldldld',
    productName: 'Hblalalala',
    files: ['./dist'],
    directories: {
        buildResources: 'resources',
        output: 'release',
    },
    asarUnpack: '**\\*.{node,dll,exe}',
    extraResources: ['build/', 'resources/'],
    win: {
        target: ['nsis'],
        sign: 'scripts/sign.js',
        signingHashAlgorithms: ['sha256'],
    },
    nsis: {
        guid: 'bbbbbbb',
        include: 'build/installer.nsh',
        artifactName: 'blalflflvl.${ext}',
        runAfterFinish: false,
        createStartMenuShortcut: false,
        createDesktopShortcut: false,
    },
};
```

I build the renderer process using `vite`:

```
import path from 'path';

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import sassDts from 'vite-plugin-sass-dts';

import { version } from './package.json';

export default defineConfig(() => ({
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'renderer'),
    server: {
        port: 4200,
        open: true,
    },
    base: './',
    build: { outDir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist') },
    plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths(), sassDts()],
    resolve: { alias: { '@/styles': path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'renderer', 'styles') } },
    define: {
        __PACKAGE_VERSION__: JSON.stringify(version),
    },
}));
```

And I build the main process using `webpack`:

```
import path from 'path';

import webpack from 'webpack';
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals';
import TsconfigPathsPlugin from 'tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin';
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';

/**
 * The function returns the OS target for compilation
 * @returns the OS target
 */
const getOsTarget = () => {
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        return 'windows';
    }

    if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
        return 'darwin';
    }

    return null;
};

const osTarget = getOsTarget();

if (osTarget === null) {
    console.log('Failed to build, unsupported platform');

    process.exit(1);
}

const rootPath = path.join(__dirname, '..');
const applicationCodePath = path.join(rootPath, 'app');
const distPath = path.join(rootPath, 'dist');
const nodeModulesPath = path.join(rootPath, 'node_modules');

const configuration: webpack.Configuration = {
    mode: 'production',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
            NODE_ENV: 'production',
        }),
    ],
    target: 'electron-main',
    entry: {
        main: path.join(applicationCodePath, 'main', 'main.ts'),
        preload: path.join(applicationCodePath, 'preload', 'main.ts'),
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals({ modulesDir: path.join(rootPath, 'node_modules') })],
    output: {
        path: distPath,
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: { type: 'umd' },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            configFile: path.join(rootPath, 'tsconfig.build.json'),
                            transpileOnly: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts'],
        modules: [applicationCodePath, nodeModulesPath],
        plugins: [
            new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
                configFile: path.join(rootPath, 'tsconfig.build.json'),
                extensions: ['.ts'],
            }),
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
            }),
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\-\[(darwin|windows)\]./, (resource) => {
            resource.request = resource.request.replace(/(darwin|windows)/, osTarget);
        }),
    ],
    node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false,
    },
};

export default configuration;
```

Then I build my complete electron application by running:

1. Build renderer process code: `vite build -c ./vite.config.ts`
2. Build main process code: `webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.config.prod.ts`
3. Build electron: `electron-builder --config ./electron.build.cjs`

Then everything goes fine. When I inspect the results in my `release` folder I can see this file: `./release/win-unpacked/resources/app.asar`. When I unpack it using `npx asar unpack app.asar app.unpack` I can inspect the `app.asar` file. Then I can see the following file exists: `./app.unpack/node_modules/async/apply.js`. Note that `apply.js` file. However, when I download the application by using the `.exe` file, I get a run time error in JS Code:

Uncaught exception:
Error: Cannot find module './apply`
Require Stack:
"........./resources/app.asar/node_modules/async/index.js"

And when I unpack, again with same way, this `.../resources/app.asar` file, the file indeed does not exist. So why this file is missing while installing the `.exe` file?

I want this file to exist